# Boolean NOT is not working with Date Range Query in Lucene.net v3.0.3.0

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, zend-search-lucene

I am using Lucene.net v3.0.3.0 for indexing and searching, I have "CreateDateTime" field which store document creation datetime.I would like to Create DateTime range query with boolean "NOT" condition. Means I would like to retrieve all those documents whose CreateDate should not be in the range which I have given, I am able to create query but the query is not returning any results.

Date is mmddyyyyhhmmss format.

my date range is 7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM To 3/31/2015 11:59:59 PM

My final query is as follows,

-CreateDateTime:[20140715000000000 TO 20150331235959000]

I had tried same query with the help of Luke tool as well it is also not returning any result. The indexing was created normally and I am able to fire all types of quires on it except DateRange query with NOT Boolean condition. NOT is working perfectly fine on other fields.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your only query in the search request? You can't just provide a negative query, you need some matching queries too. Add a MatchAllDocsQuery to your BooleanQuery, the result should end up as `*:* -CreateDateTime:[...]`